# What would be a proper way of integration testing JavaScript interacting with local storage?

Tags: javascript, testing, tdd, integration-testing, bdd

After listening to the JavaScript Weekly podcast, where I heard about the [jQueryLocalStorageTexteareas](https://github.com/micho/jquery.localStorageTextareas) plugin, I decided to try to implement this myself.

What it basically does is save a textarea's content to the browser's local storage if supported by the browser.

My question is, how would I write this in a TDD style? How would the highest level test implementation look like? It should probably be something like

```
when I type foo in a text area
and I close the page
and I open it again
then the text area should contain foo
```

Is it worth using something like Selenium to implement these kind of tests? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a testing framework built for the job, such as qUnit. [jQuery-offline](https://github.com/wycats/jquery-offline/blob/b2139ff18cb74a2cad252f51040af07cbc512d9d/public/tests/test.offline.js) uses it to good effect to test caching of text using `localStorage` for browsers with and without native support.